# How do you set up multiple environments for a virtual Unity/C# development team using Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, bitbucket, virtual-machine

Title - I've got a small team, me (novice coder, project manager/owner) and a lead developer (located abroad) and I've been tasked with hosting a cloud server or VM that will be used for the development of a video game in Unity. My goal is to have one environment spun up that is dedicated to testing and development sandbox, then a second environment that's considered the "production" or the master environment. We would then need to integrate BitBucket so that our repo feeds directly into the two environments. My understanding is that this would enable the international developer to write code and share it with me abroad.

I'm using Google Cloud Platform to set up the infrastructure but there does not appear to be a clear tutorial to accomplish my goal. I've looked into Kubernetes and Agones but both have led me down the path of creating multiplayer game servers which I don't need at this stage.

Any help would be appreciated - seems like the ask is simple enough but there doesn't appear to be a clear instruction for someone non-technical like me to pick up and use.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you need a VM for this? Using [Unity Teams](https://unity.com/products/unity-teams) and using the feature [Collaborate](https://unity.com/unity/features/collaborate) along with some sort of source control such as Git is a lot easier. Is there a specific reason you need to share an actual environment? Generally, instead of a VM this is done in branches. Have a Master branch for production then various branches for your in development portion. Merge together when deemed needed.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Honestly, because I'm a foolish newbie who's making life harder for himself lol. In all my google searches, Unity Teams and Collaborate never came up - Thanks for shedding some light. Going to do some reading now.

Comment: No worries everyone has to start somewhere. Was just not sure if there was a specific reason you would need the shared virtual machine. I am working on a remote project with a small team. We do not even use Collaborate. If you properly use source control there should be no issue with the project. When properly branching data and merging when necessary remote projects are rather smooth sailing. If you are new to source control, I would suggest using a GUI tool such as SouceTree or GitKraken unless you want to use the command line.

Comment: [Here is a useful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISW2nS_v3Ic&ab_channel=Unity) that might give you an idea of what you might want to do. It goes over how to integrate version control into Unity. As long as all the contributors follow a standard of branching and not causing merge conflicts (which can be automatically or manually resolved) there should be little to no issues working remotely.

Comment: @TEEBQNE developing with Unity in a bigger team and we never even tried Collab ... simply using git is totally sufficient ^^

Comment: @derHugo Same, personally I do not have a use case Collaborate either and just use git. Just thought with the talk of VM and cloud server, an alternative could be offered using Collaborate. Wasn't sure of the level of connectivity was needed from the question.

Comment: @TEEBQNE & derHugo - Thanks for your input and subsequent discussion. This is exactly what my team needed, I'm very grateful!